# COM: How to pass a enum argument in Invoke method (C++)

Tags: c++, com

I am going to call a COM method in C++ code. 
The COM method requires to pass in a enum argument. The enum type is also defined in the COM library.

```
CComDispatchDriver object;
object.CoCreateInstance(L"Server.RequestManager");

const int NUM_PARAMS = 1;
// The argument actually should be a enum type, but I don't know how to do that.
CComVariant vParams[NUM_PARAMS] = {0};  

CComVariant results;
::VariantInit(&results);
HRESULT hr = session.InvokeN(L"Method", vParams, NUM_PARAMS, &results);



// COM definition is something like this

//
// Type library items
//

enum __declspec(uuid("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"))
DataType
{
    DataType_Insert = 0,
    DataType_Update = 1,
    DataType_Delete = 2
};


struct __declspec(uuid("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"))
IRequestManager : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Wrapper methods for error-handling
    //

    IRequestPtr CreateMethod (enum DataType dataType );
```

Comment: Have you tried `vParams[0] = DataType_Update` for example? this enum is an int32, and CComVariant understands that.

Comment: DataType definition is in IDL, not in C++, so DataType_Update is not available in C++ code. I put a value 0 into the vParams. But it does not work..

Comment: If you don't have DataType in a h file, then you can change your IDL. But anyway, `vParams[0] = 0;` (or any integer) should work.